# Cannot resolve symbol 'x'

Tags: java, android

Hello I'm starting in Android Studio and I wanted to know how to pass from one activity to another. I've tried different methods which I've seen in youtube tutorials but all of them show me the same error:

> Cannot resolve symbol 'activity_menu'.

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Here is my code:

```
public class Menu extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button boton_start;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

        boton_start=(Button) findViewById(R.id.boton_menu);

        boton_start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent in = new Intent(activity_menu.this,activity_dishes.class);
                startActivity(in);


            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

The same happens with the other activity, but I suppose that the solution is the same for both.

Comment: This isn't JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've mentioned the layout file names instead of name of the activities

Your code:

`Intent in = new Intent(activity_menu.this,activity_dishes.class);`

It should be:

`Intent in = new Intent(Menu.this,Dishes.class);`

Mention the name of the activity, not layout files.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting activity_menu like this: `R.layout.activity_menu`